# a rails partial but used by multiple views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views

I have a piece of code that I would like to have show up on several areas... from two different views.  Which is to say handled by two different controllers (all the data comes from a helper though) what is the best way to break this up, should these partials be rendered then as lay outs?  Though they use the twitter bootstrap modal and I have had huge issues getting those to show correctly when called from a layout (most the reason why I have to break up this code into a partial, one that comes from one `index.erb.html` and another that comes from a partial of its own `_document_header.erb.html` good time to ask, can you stuff one partial within another...

so just trying to get some pointers.  This code is really common to two views.
(and is not always needing to be rendered or displayed)...so want to do this the best way.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Shared partials go in the `shared` directory.

Comment: that might of answered it, shared partials.  Basically a partial that any view can see and use.  Thanks I will research 'shared partials' I think that was the vocabulary I was looking for!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference a partial that is anywhere in your views folder.

It's common to make a "shared" folder in your views and reference the partial like: `<%= render 'shared/my_partial' %>`

Comment: More on shared partials in the official docs here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials